# JavaScript: Functional mapping?

Tags: javascript, loops, functional-programming

Is there a more succinct way to write this?

```
var me = {};

for (var i in you) {
 me[i] = you[i];
}
```

(where `you` is an arbitrarily-lengthed JavaScript array)

In other words, given the input of:

```
var you = [
 "what",
 "r",
 "u"
];
```

The output, `me`, becomes:

```
me = {
 0: "what",
 1: "r",
 2: "u"
};
```

Like, a one-liner that uses some functional method?

Comment: actually your example will give `me = {0: "what",1: "r", 2: "u",length:3 /*And anything from Array's prototype*/};`

Comment: Because you asked for ["Functional" JavaScript](http://osteele.com/sources/javascript/functional/)... :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why do you want to do this? Arrays in JavaScript **are** Objects, except with some additional properties like `slice`, `splice`, `push` and `length`.

Internally, Arrays and Objects are stored exactly in the same way: e.g. `array[0]` is the **same** as `array["0"]`, or `object["0"]` (unlike in other languages where adjacent array indices are in fact in adjacent memory - array "indices" are simply converted into strings in JavaScript).

So, if you just want to copy the data, then this will suffice:

```
me = you.slice(); // me is a copy of you, but is still an array
```

Or, if you really want some sort of mapping functionality, then [underscore.js](http://documentcloud.github.com/underscore/) provides a whole collection of functional programming tools for your perusal.

Comment: I'm trying to improve this: https://github.com/prettycode/String.prototype.format.js/blob/master/String.prototype.format.js

Comment: @Agile, the way `args` is used in that code, the conversion into `replace` is completely unecessary. Take that `else` block out and see if it works ;)

Comment: +1 for underscore. if his question made sense, underscore would have the answer

Answer (score 1):

There is no built-in function that does what you ask, however some of the widely used javascript libraries like jQuery provide such a function. In jQuery's case: [`jQuery.extend()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.extend/)

Usage:

```
var me = {};
jQuery.extend(me,someObject);

//or, equivalently -
var me2 = jQuery.extend({},someObject);
```

Answer (score 0):

jQuery has an `extend()` function ([documentation here](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.extend/)).  Your code would look like this:

```
var me = {};
var you = ["what", "r", "u"];
$.extend(me, you);
```

This would allow you to do things like:

```
alert("Second element: " + me[1]);
```

It's a little odd, but I think it's what you're looking for.

Answer (score 0):

I saw what you were trying to achieve with your string formatter. Instead of answering your original question of coming up with a concise implementation of one portion of it, I'll suggest a concise (and more flexible) implementation for the whole thing:

```
String.prototype.format = function () {
    var args = arguments;

    return this.replace(/\{(?:(\d+)|(\w+))\}/g, function (s, idx, prop) {
        return prop && args[0]
            ? args[0][prop]
            : args[idx];
    });
};
```

When you have a number `n` inside a token `"{n}"`, it uses the n-th argument for replacement. Otherwise, for non-numerical keys, it picks the corresponding property of the first argument.

For example:

```
"I have {1} {name}s in my basket.".replace({ type: "fruit", name: "eggplant" }, 4);
```

Returns:

```
"I have 4 eggplants in my basket."
```

Answer (score 0):

The underscore.js library also has a basic extend function.

`var me = _({}).extend(you)`

or

```
var me = {}
_(me).extend(you)
```

or

```
var me = {}
_.extend(me, you)
```